# How to draw like this in drawRect?

Tags: iphone, touch, drawrect

iPhone developing problem: 
I want to draw a quadrangle with the four black corners (CGPoint) of quadrangle changeable. 
I overrode the `drawRect` method but it shows only rectangle instead of quadrangle. Is that mean `drawRect` can only draw Rectangles with four CGPoints?

The original requirement is changing the shape of quadrangle by touching and moving any of the corner points. Can I solve this by override `drawRect` ? should I do something else?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`-drawRect:` is where you put your drawing code, and that code can draw just about anything you want. You are certainly not limited to rectangles. I'm not sure I follow the particular nature of your problem -- it would help a lot if you'd post some code. In general `-drawRect:` is the right place to put your drawing code, and if your view isn't drawing the way you want it to it's very likely due to a problem in your code rather than a limitation of the `-drawRect:` method.

Answer (score 0):

specifically, your view's frame defines its `origin{x,y}`, and `size{width,height}`.

this is a simple rectangle.

as well, a rectangle is passed for drawing arguments.

to have your view represent a quadrilateral more complex than a rectangle, you must write some custom geometry conversions (unless a function already exists). there are many apis to ease this (e.g. NSBezierPath/UIBezierPath).

ultimately, you want a frame which is large enough to contain the entire quadrilateral. when requested to draw a portion of it, you determine what to draw an how to fill it.

since you want 4 movable points within the rect, you must define 4 points (e.g. CGPoint) -- one for each corner. make these ivars of your view's subclass. when they change, invalidate the view as is appropriate.

Comment: thanks a lot! Would you please tell me how to change the value of 4 points and show it on the screen? I asked about this question here with code inside : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775557/how-to-let-drawrect-get-the-value-of-points-from-viewcontroller-and-draw